# List of objects in Mustache

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mustache

I am working on rendering HTML from mustache template engine.

I am stuck in rendering when it comes to deal with a list of objects.

Here is my object:

```
var Prod={
  "Object1": {
    "name": "name1",
    "category": "laptop"
  },
  "Object2": {
    "name": "name2",
    "category": "laptop"
  },
  "Object3": {
    "name": "name3",
    "category": "Desktop"
  },
  "Object4": {
    "name": "name4",
    "category": "Mobile"
  }
}
```

Here is what I am trying to render from:

```
var template='{{#Prod}} {{name}} and {{category}} {{/Prod}}'

 Mustache.render(template, {"Prod":Prod});
```

But it is not working, and I do not understand why.

Please suggest me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your list of products an array for the automatic iteration of lists functionality to kick in. No need to have each product accessible by keys `Object1`, `Object2`, `Object3`, etc.

**Edit:** If you can't change the object format, you can turn one format into the other fairly easily using `Object.keys` and `Array#map`:

```js
var Prod={
  "Object1": {
    "name": "name1",
    "category": "laptop"
  },
  "Object2": {
    "name": "name2",
    "category": "laptop"
  },
  "Object3": {
    "name": "name3",
    "category": "Desktop"
  },
  "Object4": {
    "name": "name4",
    "category": "Mobile"
  }
}

var products = Object.keys(Prod).map(function (k) { return this[k] }, Prod)

document.body.innerHTML = Mustache.render('\
<ul>\
  {{#products}}\
  <li>{{name}} and {{category}}</li>\
  {{/products}}\
</ul>\
', { products: products })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `Prod` is an object and not a list.

If you change your code to the following, I believe it should work.

```
var Prod = [
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "category": "laptop"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "category": "laptop"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "category": "Desktop"
  },
  {
    "name": "name4",
    "category": "Mobile"
  }
}

var template='{{#Prod}} {{name}} and {{category}} {{/Prod}}'

Mustache.render(template, { "Prod":Prod});
```

Comment: I can't change object format. Please suggest the solution for current object format

Comment: Can you change it in the render function?  E.G. render(template, {Prod: Object.keys(Prod).map(key => Prod[key]))?